# How to display nodes based on the taxonomy terms of the current logged in user, with multiple vocabularies?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, taxonomy-terms

**Say I have 3 taxonomy vocabularies:**

Products, Professions and Support

**Each vocabulary has 2 terms:**

Products -> *product1*, *product2*

Professions -> *profession1*, *profession2*

Support -> *support1*, *support2*

**Users can be tagged with terms. User A is tagged with:**

product1 and support1

**Nodes can be tagged with terms. Node 1 is tagged with:**

product1

**Node 2 is tagged with:**

support1

**Node 3 is tagged with:**

profession1

So when **User A** logs in and goes to the view, they should see **Node 1** and **Node 2** only. I can't seem to achieve this in views. It's possible when there is just one vocabulary, but i can't seem to get it done when there are multiple vocabularies involved. Can anyone help without coding? Or perhaps I need to use code?

Comment: You add a taxonomy field in user profile?

Comment: Hi, this was 6 months ago now :), I used a work around of just having one taxonomy vocabulary instead of 3 - But yes I had a field in the user profile for the taxonomy

Comment: I didn't recognize the date. Sry. :P

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this **using fields instead of taxonomy**? I personally prefer using fields over taxonomy since fields are more flexible with views. In your case, if your site is still under development I suggest you to use fields and try out the same.

Comment: Hi Sharan,

Thanks for your response. In the end I just went for the one vocabulary and structured it accordingly. Thanks for the field suggestion, i'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong...am thinking current user in relationships, and in filters using the users taxonomy field and matching it with the contents taxonomy. Comments?